# DotNetNuke WebForm Alert Dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am currently developing a DotNetNuke module. However, I failed to prompt user an alert dialog box in certain situations like record duplication.

I am using the following code to display an alert box in Controller class.

```
EditForm edForm = new EditForm();
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(edForm, edForm.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

The following is my full code.

Form.ascx.cs

```
void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UdtController.UpdateRow(Data, ModuleId, False);
}
```

UdtController.cs

```
public void UpdateRow(DataSet ds, int rowNr, bool isDataToImport)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    string strIsUnique = "";
    foreach (DataRow field in ds.Tables[DataSetTableName.Fields].Rows)
    {
        var strColumnName = field[FieldsTableColumn.Title].ToString();
        strIsUnique = field[FieldsTableColumn.Searchable].ToString();

        var strValueColumn = ((!isDataToImport &&
                               ds.Tables[DataSetTableName.Data].Columns.Contains(strColumnName +
                                                                                 DataTableColumn.
                                                                                     Appendix_Original))
                                  ? strColumnName + DataTableColumn.Appendix_Original
                                  : strColumnName);


        if (strIsUnique == "True")
        {
            int uniqueDataCount = FieldController.uniqueData(currentRow[strValueColumn].AsString());

            if (uniqueDataCount == 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[DataSetTableName.Data].Columns.Contains(strValueColumn))
                {
                    values.Add(field[FieldsTableColumn.Id].AsInt(), currentRow[strValueColumn].AsString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EditForm edForm = new EditForm();
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(edForm, edForm.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ds.Tables[DataSetTableName.Data].Columns.Contains(strValueColumn))
            {
                values.Add(field[FieldsTableColumn.Id].AsInt(), currentRow[strValueColumn].AsString());
            }
        }
    }
    FieldController.UpdateData(userDefinedRowId, values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `Page`, not create a new form.

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;   
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

However DNN has it's own message box you could use:

http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/UIPatterns/AlertDialog.html

Comment: It does not show dialog box also. I am just curious. If the same method I applied it in normal ASP.Net Web Form application. It works but it does not work in DotNetNuke application

Comment: I can assure you that this works, even in DNN (tested). Are you sure the code is even reached? What is the value of `strIsUnique`?

Comment: The value for strIsUnique is true

Comment: Is it `true` or `True`? Apart from that I recommend using real booleans instead of strings as boolean. To prevent such possible errors. What happens if you put my snippet all the way on top, just after `public void UpdateRow(DataSet ds, int rowNr, bool isDataToImport)`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it woks for me.